# type definition not found with jaxb

Tags: jaxb

I'm able to generate java classes running mvn clean install with jaxb on https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/da92f8b0c8530061c539dcfc5c0257ce8565568b/jdk-8-alpine/Dockerfile, but if i try to generate on my local machine ubuntu 14, same java and maven version i'm getting the following error. Any suggestion on how to fix it?
Thanks,
Jorge

```
    enterCommonReqRsp.xsd file

<xs:include schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>

<!--*** Request Types ***-->
<xs:complexType name="BaseReq">                
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="BaseCoreReq">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="OverridePCC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="RetrieveProviderReservationDetails" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>


 SharedBookingReqRsp.xsd file

   <xs:import namespace="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v42_0" schemaLocation="../common_v42_0/CommonReqRsp.xsd"/>
   <xs:complexType name="BookingBaseReq">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>Context for Requests</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="common:BaseReq"/>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>


SharedBookingReqRsp.xsd; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 46; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'common:BaseReq' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4156)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4139)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1745)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:191)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1434)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:633)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:572)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:360)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:473)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Most probably your schema is invalid. But it is not possible to say how exactly without seeing it. Post the schema files or links to them and I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can find schemas at https://github.com/Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial-c-sharp/tree/master/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/Wsdl/common_v32_0 , however the weird thing is that it is working on another env configuration. Thanks

Comment: I could compile these schemas without problems: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support/tree/master/t/travelport

Comment: Try to putt together a minimal verifiable complete test project and share it on github. Something I could check out and build.

Comment: Seems that setting <strict>false</strict> according to 
https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuring-Extension-Validation-and-XML-Security did the work. So i guess somehow it is disabled in my local environment but it is enabled in jenkins environment. Unfortunatelly i don't have access to the server to check configuration right now.